# How to include Wordpress header/footer in CGI script

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, perl, cgi

I have a CGI script that creates, searches, and edits a MySQL database. The database is actually a searchable listing of burials for a cemetery, similar to this: http://www.cowlitzcemetery2.org/burials/ It is based off a program called "FlatText for MySQL" which is no longer available online.

Anyway, I am trying to set up this script for a new cemetery, but they use WordPress for their main site. I would like to use this script, but import the WordPress header and footer around the script output, so that the search results match the rest of the web site. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: why not rewrite your script in php itself, which is what WP's written in? Then it'd be trivial to embed WP in your script.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but it requires you to know about Perl, HTML and probably PHP or the Wordpress sphere. As it stands, your question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. Rewriting in PHP and creating a Wordpress plugin is one way to go. Making a page in Wordpress that holds an `<iframe>` and putting your script in there is another one.

Comment: Thank you. I do have knowledge of Perl, HTML, PHP, and Wordpress. I just don't know of a way to include the PHP header/footer from wordpress in a CGI file. If it was the other way around (including CGI in a PHP file), that would be easier. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Look here : https://metacpan.org/pod/Template
Or use easier way .. templatize it yourself

Grab entire wordpress page into your cgi script after the **DATA** section
and do something like this instead of printing:

```
my $output = '';
...
$output.="string1\n";
...
$output.="string2\n";

$/ = undef;
my $page = <DATA>

$page =~ s/<CONTENT>/$output/;

print $page;


__DATA__
<html>
wordpress page begin
<CONTENT>
wordpres page footer
</html>
```

Comment: WordPress pages typically include a lot of dynamically generated content (such as tag clouds, lists of recent comments, and different menu items depending on if you are logged in or not). Hard coding a snapshot of that from a certain point in time will break all of that.